# jquery ui out: function not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

In jquery-ui documentation it says **out:** function is triggered when an accepted draggable is dragged out of the droppable. But in my case I want both the container to be draggable and droppable. Also I want the div with id droppable to be sortable as well. For now drag and drop works fine but when I drag out one of the item the out function is not triggered so how can I do that.

html

```
<div id="droppable" class="draggable droppable sortable">
</div>
<div id="draggable" class="droppable draggable sortable">
    <p id="hello11" class="item">Hello1</p>
    <p id="hello22" class="item">Hello2</p>
    <p id="hello33" class="item">Hello3</p>
    <p id="hello44" class="item">Hello4</p>
    <p id="hello55" class="item">Hello5</p>
</div>
<div id="form-container">
    <form method="post" action="">
        <!-- Do stuff here -->
        <input type="text" id ="hello1" name="xoxo1" value="">
        <input type="text" id ="hello2" name="xoxo2" value="">
        <input type="text" id ="hello3" name="xoxo3" value="">
        <input type="text" id ="hello4" name="xoxo4" value="">
        <input type="text" id ="hello5" name="xoxo5" value="">
    </form>
</div>
```

script.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
        accept: ".item"
    });
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      accept: ".item",
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        // Set values
        var myid = ui.draggable.attr("id").toString();
        myid = myid.substring(0, myid.length - 1);
        document.getElementById(myid).value = myid;
      },
      out: function(event,ui){
        // Unset the values
        var myid = ui.draggable.attr("id").toString();
        myid = myid.substring(0, myid.length - 1);
        document.getElementById(myid).value = '';
      }
    });

    $( ".sortable" ).sortable();

    $( ".draggable .item" ).draggable({
      connectToSortable: ".sortable"
    });
});
```

[Here is a fiddle for that](http://jsfiddle.net/Puni/rkx53c2r/)

Comment: Would you provide fiddle for this?

Comment: Sorry I don't have this on jsfiddle , I am working on my local machine. @ParagBhayani

Comment: what draggable droppable plugin you are using?

Comment: Please update this fiddle so that I can help you out ... https://jsfiddle.net/3eefs2kp/

Comment: I am using jQuery ui . Ok I'll sign up for jsfiddle and let you know

Comment: Here is link to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Puni/rkx53c2r/

It does not work exactly as in my local computer here in jsfiddle and I've never used it so I don't if you can get it. @ParagBhayani

Comment: One thing I noticed here is you just have one element as droppable, you should put both element as droppable

Comment: I've tried by adding the following code but still it does not work

 $(".droppable").droppable({
        accept: ".item"
    });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what you're trying to do is two connected sortables, which is already handled by `sortable` widget. You have pretty much the same event, `drop` is pretty much equivalent to `receive`, and `out` works as well.

It's not completely clear what the end result should be, but this should give you some ideas:

```
    $(".sortable").sortable({
        connectWith: '.sortable',
        receive: function (event, ui) {
            // Set values
            var myid = ui.item.attr("id").toString();
            myid = myid.substring(0, myid.length - 1);
            document.getElementById(myid).value = myid;
        },
        out: function (event, ui) {
            // Unset the values
             console.log('out')
            var myid = ui.item.attr("id").toString();
            myid = myid.substring(0, myid.length - 1);
            document.getElementById(myid).value = myid;
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lhn3zo0s/2/

Comment: What you did is really great, the drag functionalities become very smooth. Hmm... not exactly as I wanted, but I got the idea of changing my initial approach from your answer. I really really appreciate for your answer. Thank You